# Unable to move foward on a Riemann equation - unsure if I can move the fraction upwards to then solve the integral.

Tags: calculus, integration

If there's any issue on the writing I deeply apologize. I only own an old and laggy phone to use the internet. It's a bit hard to write things down.

Initial Equation:

$$20(\cos(x) + \sin(x)) 
           e^{x + 2}$$

I know that I can move the fraction ($e^{x + 2}$, in this case) up and multiply it alongside the ${20(\cdots)}$

$$\int20e^{−x−2}(\sin(x)+\cos(x))dx$$

But do I move the $20e^{-x-2}$ out? Do I only move out the $20$ and only keep the $e^{-x-2}$ inside the ∫?

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to

Comment: **Hint:** Write it as $$20\left(\int e^{x+2} \sin(x)~dx + \int e^{x+2} \cos(x)~dx \right)$$ Solve the second integral using integration by parts and then simplify.

Comment: Thank you! I think I managed to do it :)